# Is there any other way to install the libxml2-devel library in Centos?

Tags: centos7, yum, libxml2

I need to install **libxml2-devel and libxslt-devek** in Centos 7.4 but I can't use yum. When I try to install the libraries I receive the same error:

> Failed to initialize NSS library.

I Followed all the different solutions here: https://serverfault.com/questions/866294/error-failed-to-initialize-nss-library , but I had no result.

```
COMMAND: sudo yum install libxml2-devel
```

error:

> Failed to initialize NSS library

There was a problem importing one of the Python modules required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:

> cannot import name ts
>
> Please install a package which provides this module, or verify that
>   the module is installed correctly.

It's possible that the above module doesn't match the
current version of Python, which is:
2.7.5 (default, Aug  4 2017, 00:39:18) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-16)]